# Tensorflow 2.0.1 training freezes the system

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I am training a GAN using tensorflow 2.0.1's `gradienttape()`. The training goes around till 2000/2562 batches in the 0th epoch and freezes the system. I've even limited the gpu memory to 8GB:

```
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=8172)])
```

**System Configuration:**
GPU : Nvidia 1080ti 11GB memory
RAM : 16GB DDR4
Tensorflow verison : 2.0.1
Cuda version : 10.0
OS : Ubuntu 18.04

I can provide the code if you require.
Note: Tensorflow was built from source

Comment: why did you build from source

Answer (score 0):

The cause of a system freeze is really difficult to pinpoint. In your case, I would start by installing a pre-compiled version of tensorflow using pip.

If you observe the same symptoms, I would suspect either a too weak power supply or a problem with the ventilation of your PC.

In order to check if an insufficient power supply causes the freeze, you can try to limit the current used by your GPU with:

`nvidia-smi.exe" -i 0 -pl 100`

This will limit the power used by your card to 100W (1080Ti peak consumption should be around 250W-300W when not limited). The training will be slower, but if it doesn't crash anymore power supply.

You can also use `nvidia-smi` to monitor the GPU temperature and check if it stays within acceptable limits.